# Unable suspend-to-ram USB devices driver for the first time in kernel 4.4

Tags: linux-kernel, suspend

I am working on Linux kernel 4.4.55, my case is: when I suspend my system by the command

```
$ echo mem > /sys/power/state
```

And once USB devices were plugged into board, the first suspend is failed.
After that, enter the above command again, the second suspend is successful. It's very weird.

I continued to investigate the **usb core** component (.../drivers/usb/core/), I found out that: the first suspend failed because of function *usb_port_runtime_suspend()* returned error code of "-EAGAIN" when it invoked function

```
    if (dev_pm_qos_flags(&port_dev->dev, PM_QOS_FLAG_NO_POWER_OFF)
            == PM_QOS_FLAGS_ALL){  
        printk("DEBUG: %d : %s\n", __LINE__, __func__); /* my debug code */
        return -EAGAIN;
  }
```

According to my understand,

- The PM QoS "no power off" flag indicates to the kernel that power should not  be removed entirely from the device
- When usb device is suspending, usb core will suspend usb port and usb port runtime pm callback will clear PORT_POWER feature to power off port if all conditions were met.

I don't know WHY function **dev_pm_qos_flags()** returned PM_QOS_FLAGS_ALL in my case, anyone can explain this ? and is it an error ? Because EAGAIN is caused by **pm qos NO_POWER_OFF** setting, this is not an error for usb port system pm.

Comment: probably a good question for LKML... What version of the kernel did it work with?

Comment: The kernel 3.10 worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, need to understand HOW the S2RAM works, able to follow the below flowchart (drawn by myself)
[image]

I already detected the issue happening in USB Host controller.